# Propel 1.2 PropePager Issue

Tags: php, propel

a question for the Propel veterans here, since it's a very old version:

I have an issue with the Propel Pager and a having clause. The Criteria is:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$criterion = $c->getNewCriterion(EfEventsPeer::EF_STAMMDATEN_ID, $stamm_id);
$criterion->addAnd($c->getNewCriterion(EfEventsPeer::GELOESCHT, 1, Criteria::NOT_EQUAL));
$criterion->addAnd($c->getNewCriterion(EfEventDatenPeer::ID, null, Criteria::ISNOTNULL));
$criterion->addAnd($c->getNewCriterion(EfEventsPeer::IMPORTIERT, 1, Criteria::NOT_EQUAL));    
$c->addJoin(EfEventDatenPeer::EF_EVENTS_ID, EfEventsPeer::ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
$c->addGroupByColumn(EfEventsPeer::ID);
$c->addHaving($c->getNewCriterion(EfEventDatenPeer::DATUM,  "MAX(".EfEventDatenPeer::DATUM.") < '" . date('Y-m-d') . "'", Criteria::CUSTOM));
$c->add($criterion);
$c->addDescendingOrderByColumn(EfEventsPeer::GESPERRT);
$c->addDescendingOrderByColumn(EfEventsPeer::EINGESTELLT_AM);
$c->setDistinct();
```

The generated SQL Code works fine in phpmyadmin. I get the expected result (around 200 entries).

```
SELECT DISTINCT FROM ef_events WHERE ((ef_events.EF_STAMMDATEN_ID=? AND ef_events.GELOESCHT<>?) AND ef_events.IMPORTIERT<>?) ORDER BY ef_events.GESPERRT DESC,ef_events.EINGESTELLT_AM DESC
```

I also get the correct result with my usual doSelect statement:

```
$results = EfEventsPeer::doSelect($c);
```

However, if I try to get the same results using the PropelPager, I always get a totalRecordCount of 1 and 1 page.

```
$pager = new PropelPager($c, 'EfEventsPeer', 'doSelect', 1, 10);
$pager->getTotalRecordCount();  //returns 1
$pager->getTotalPages(); //returns 1
```

Strangely, I do get the number of hitsPerPage (in this case 10) in my result if available. When I loop through

```
foreach($pager->getResult() as $single_event){
  ...
}
```

Im sure the issue must be a wrong addHaving criterion, but I can't solve it myself.

Any ideas? Thx a lot!